# Replacing text by looking up in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some text that might look like this:

```
string str = "Dear Fred, Yours sincerely [Project Manager]";
```

or, it might look like this:

```
string str = "Dear Fred, Yours sincerely [Administrator]";
```

or any one of ten people 'signing' an email for a particular project. On the page I am working on I have a dataset that contains 10 rows with two columns with data like:

```
[Project Manager] .... Fred Smith
[Administrator] ..... Arthur Jones
[Coordinator] .... Belinda Digby
```

(The dots between the data in the rows above is to try and indicate tablular data as in a recordset.)

When I am displaying the string str in a text box, how can I 'look up' who the [Project Manager'] is 
- or the [Administrator'] from the dataset - so I can replace the Placeholder with the correct name?

Comment: What are the names of the columns in the dataset?

Comment: Role and Who are the names of the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by DataSet you mean the Ado.net DataSet object with a DataTable and 10 rows then this is one way:

```
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    dataTable.TableName = "Managers";
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Role"));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Who"));

    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    dataRow[0] = "Singer";
    dataRow[1] = "Johnny Cash";
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);

    dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    dataRow[0] = "Banjo guy";
    dataRow[1] = "Cleetus Smith";
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);

    dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

    String thisGuyIs = "Banjo guy";
    String hisNameIs = "This is our guy: {0}";

    DataRow[] foundRows;

    foundRows = dataSet.Tables["Managers"].Select("Role = '" + thisGuyIs + "'");

    if (foundRows.Count() == 1) {
        hisNameIs = String.Format(hisNameIs, foundRows[0]["Who"].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I keep forgetting about Linq.